# How to get a Github webhook running with Gitbook via private repository?

Tags: github, repository, private, webhooks, gitbook

I have a private github repository integrated into gitbook.io to be able to edit the book online within gitbooks editor. However, the webhook gitbook initiated in github does not trigger any builds after pushing to the repository.

Any ideas?